# How do you simplify cos^4(x) by using power reducing formulae?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you simplify $\cos^4(x)$ using the power reducing formula?

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean using $\cos^2x=(1+\cos2x)/2$, so
$$
\cos^4x=\frac{1}{4}(1+2\cos2x+\cos^22x)
$$
Now apply the same to $\cos^22x$.

Comment: That helped me. Thanks!